# Change Colour of Cells in DataGridView according to current/expired Time only

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm working with datagridview which is populated from an excel file source.

I have a column "Time". I want to change colour of Cells in column "Time" So that the expired Time (cells) are coloured gray and next available times (cells) are green etc.

I feel its more complicated than I think it is, as the time entered in Excel represents a date too even though currently its only entered as hh:mm AM/PM format. Also DateTime.Now brings up the System Date + Time.

Example:

Right now its 11PM (current time, anything before this is expired). The Cells in column "Time" have values which are earlier and later than the current time. 10:52PM and ealier are all expired now and 11:50pm and later are all available time slots.

```
   public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        dataGridView1.CellPainting += dataGridView1_CellPainting;
    }
```

///////////////////////////////////

```
   private void loadListBox4()
    {
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection MyConnection;
        System.Data.DataSet DtSet;
        System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter MyCommand;
        MyConnection = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection(@"provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source= C:\Users\Dell\Documents\BusTimingExcel.xls;Extended Properties=Excel 8.0;");
        MyCommand = new System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter("select * from [Sheet1$]", MyConnection);
        //MyCommand.TableMappings.Add("Route", "Location");
        DtSet = new System.Data.DataSet();
        MyCommand.Fill(DtSet);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = DtSet.Tables[0];
        MyConnection.Close();

        dataGridView1.Columns["Time"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "t";
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
        dataGridView1.AllowUserToOrderColumns = true;
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true; ;

        DataView dv;
        dv = new DataView(DtSet.Tables[0], "Station = 'Poets Estate, The Dove'", "Time", DataViewRowState.CurrentRows);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dv;

    }
}
```

Comment: What data type does your `Time` column actually have?

Comment: dataGridView1.Columns["Time"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "t"; //its in the format hh:mm

Comment: What is the **expired time**? You have to compare the time displayed in cells against the expired time to determine the cells color.

Comment: sorry i have edited the post with example. the expired time is actually the current time. anything before "NOW" is expired anything later than NOW is available

Comment: Have you checked out my solution? leave some comment if it doesn't work or there is something unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding code to the `CellPainting` event handler and update the `Cell BackColor` there:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e){
  if(e.Value == null||
     e.ColumnIndex < 0 || e.RowIndex < 0 ||
     dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name!="Time") return;
  e.CellStyle.BackColor = ((DateTime)e.Value).TimeOfDay < DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay ?
                          Color.Gray : Color.Green;
}
//To register the event handler for CellPainting, you can use this code
dataGridView1.CellPainting += dataGridView1_CellPainting;//Place this in your form constructor
```

### UPDATE

To prevent flicker, try this code (placed in your form constructor):

```
typeof(Control).GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic |
             System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance).SetValue(dataGridView1, true, null);
```

Comment: This has confused me a little. Im using a crude approach as you can see in my code above. Ive tried your approach but its not clear to me where do i incorporate and call the event.

Comment: @user970355 it's an **event handler**, you don't call it, you have to **register** it.

Comment: Thanks but Something not right. Its not loading the datagridview properly now.

Comment: @user970355 the old code should throw exception but you didn't mention any thing about that, I updated the code, check it now. BTW, if there is something wrong, you should give some clear description so that I can improve the code

Comment: Thanks. It works but still slow. I can see the grid view is generated and the Cells are coloured as expected but the interface is very slow, I have to move the scroll bar up and down and all of sudden the Columns and Rows appear, including the colour.

Comment: @user970355 do you have many columns or rows in your grid? Again, the code I posted should throw some invalid cast exception but you still didn't mention it?

Comment: I dont know what to say? Im trying to mention as clearly as possible. :) Only 2 Columns. Currently Im filtering out rows based on a name which brings up fewer rows. Am I missing catching exceptions?

Comment: Exception : Specified Cast is not Valid

Comment: @user970355 What is the actual data type of your `Time` column? Do you know how to check it?

Comment: I dont know how to check the data type. I'm trying that now. Sorry for late response.

Comment: @user970355 you can try this code `MessageBox.Show(dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Time"].Value.GetType().ToString())`, it should show `System.DateTime`

Comment: Yes its showing System.DateTime. Now its working perfectly fine. I dont know what was happening last time. I rearranged the code a little and works great. Thank you friend! Great Help

Comment: @user970355 if so there should not have been any chance for the exception `Specified cast is not valid`, is it working for you now? Still that exception?

Comment: not showing that exception anymore. I don't know what happened. Works perfectly fine now.

Comment: @user970355 nice to know that, maybe I updated the code after you were offline.

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving us much to go on here, but to change the color of a cell in a gridview can be achieved like so:

```
dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[e.ColumnIndex].Style.ForeColor = Color.Red;
```

Now figure out how to check your condition ("expired", "available") and call the above code.

Hope that helps,

Chris

Comment: Thanks Chris. Sorry but maybe I didnt explain myself clearly. I can change the Colour to the cells but exactly as you put it "Expired" "Available" is what im trying to figure out. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This Code Works any way if you want further help tell me!

```
private void dataGridView1_CellPainting(object sender, DataGridViewCellPaintingEventArgs e)
        {

            if (((System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView)(sender)).Columns.Contains("Time"))
            {
                int Column_index = ((System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView)(sender)).Columns["Time"].Index;
                if ((e.ColumnIndex == Column_index) && (e.RowIndex != -1))
                {
                    DateTime Grid_Time = (DateTime)e.Value;
                    if (Grid_Time.TimeOfDay < DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay )
                    {
                        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Gray;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        e.CellStyle.BackColor = Color.Green;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution is working without issues. I'm trying to figure out the datatype for column "Time". Thanks again.

Comment: Well,that's nice when someone find his solutions SO helped many programmers around the World.
check GetType() if you want to figure out the datatype.
Sorry for late response.I was out of office for couple of hours.